# Why does celery create multiple workers for one task?

Tags: python-2.7, celery

I have one celery task which collects data from a streaming data source. The task keeps getting data until the data source closes the connection.

I used the same celery 3.1.9 and python 2.7.12 version to run the task on both Windows and Ubuntu 14.04. On Windows, there is only one worker assigned per task whereas there are more than one workers assigned on Ubuntu.

Why would it happen? And how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide the information of your celery settings.

Comment: Celery's support for Windows was shaky and they have discontinued it entirely as of 4.0.